# Formik Field not clearing after form submit

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

So I have a component which is using `formik` and has a child component to update one of the fields for it.

**Child component :**

```
 this.props.formik.setFieldValue("keywords", target.value, false);
```

This works fine to get updated value but after the form is submtted I want to clear all the fields. But somehow value for this field gets retained.

I have tried

- `Resetform`
- `setFieldValue("keywords", '', false);`
- `values.keywords = ''` in onSubmit event

and none is working

Answer (score 2):

In the onSubmit prop that is returned from `<Formik />`, you receive the values and actions associated with those values. Calling Reset `actions.resetForm()` inside of that return should solve your problem.

```
onSubmit = {
    (v: IRegisterFormValues, a: FormikActions<IRegisterFormValues> ) => {
        AuthService.register(v.email).then(
            res => {
                a.resetForm()
            }
        )
    }
}
```